# Full Text Search in mongodb and sort on weight Scores

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am new in spring data mongodb i want to convert this query in to Java spring data mongo query object. i have try setMeta() function but that does not works. please help me to convert query

```
db.event.find({$text:{$search:"Food"}},{score:{$meta:"textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

thank you,

Comment: What did you already try? What didn't work?

Comment: @OliverGierke thank you i make it done :P  using Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria)
  .sortByScore()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was trying to sort result on score of of mongo-full-text-search. i got its solution in spring-data-mongodb. i would like to share here.

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
  .matching("Food");
Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria)
  .sortByScore();

List<Event> events = template.find(query, Event.class);
```

it works for me more detail visit [spring-data-mongodb-documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/17/text-search-your-documents-with-spring-data-mongodb)